# zend framework or jquery strips my input

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I managed to include latexrender (http://www.mayer.dial.pipex.com/tex.htm) into my new Zend Framework based project and everything seems to be working fine except the ajax-based preview strips "+" sign from my formulas for some reason.

Here's my html fragment with example textarea:

```
<dt id="formula-label"><label for="formula" class="required">Formula:</label></dt>
<dd id="formula-element">
<textarea name="formula" id="formula" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<p class="description"><span class="preview-formula"></span></p></dd>

<button name="previewtformula" id="previewformula" type="button" onclick="generatePreview(&#39;formula&#39;)">Preview</button>
```

Here's the corresponding Zend form code:

```
    $formula = $this->createElement('textarea', 'formula');
    $formula->setLabel('Formula:');
    $formula->setRequired(true);
    $formula->setAttrib('rows', 5);
    $formula->setAttrib('cols', 40);
    $formula->setDescription('<span class="preview-formula"></span>');
    $formula->getDecorator('Description')->setEscape(false);
    $this->addElement($formula);

    $prevFormula = $this->createElement('button', 'preview-formula');
    $prevFormula->setAttrib('onclick', "generatePreview('formula')");
    $prevFormula->setLabel('Preview');
    $prevFormula->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $this->addElement($prevFormula);
```

javascript file:

```
function generatePreview(elem){
    var details = $('textarea#'+elem).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/formula/preview',
        async: false,
        data: 'details=' + details,
        success: function(responseText) {

            $("span.preview-"+elem).html(responseText);

        }
    });
};
```

and my controller action:

```
public function previewAction() {

   if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
                $this->_helper->Layout->disableLayout();
                $data = $this->_request->getPost();
                $latex = new My_LatexRender();
                echo nl2br($latex->latex_content($data['details']));
        } else {
            return $this->_redirect('/index');
        }
}
```

like I said everything is working fine, the images are saving to the disk nicely and formulas added to the database are intact (there are "+" signs) but when i preview the formulas it somehow got strip from all "+" signs so for example

"2+2" saves in database as "2+2" but in preview it's just "22"

not sure if there are other characters stripped, haven't noticed any so far

Comment: can you do `var_dump($latex->latex_content($data['details']);` and show what is being printed?

Comment: preview of "2-1+3/5*9(0)" results in "string '2-1 3/5*9(0)' (length=12)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution. i had to change

```
data: 'details=' + details,
```

to

```
data: {details: details},
```